# Microsoft Live authorization GET request returns Net::HTTPBadRequest 400

Tags: ruby, post, get, http-error

I am following [Microsoft live connect API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631818.aspx#authcodegrant) to authorize my user to access onedrive. I am trying to stablish code flow authentication. I got the `AUTHORIZATION_CODE` as described. Now, I am trying to get the `ACCESS_TOKEN` with the help of that:

In [Microsoft live connect API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631818.aspx#authcodegrant), its said for getting `ACCESS_TOKEN` we need to provide a request such as,

```
POST https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf

Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&
          code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&grant_type=authorization_code
```

I provided the same request using ruby and got a error:

```
#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>
```

Then I found in [microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/onedrive/en-US/4f6aaeda-2bac-4d1c-8898-e99725526fdb/getting-status-code-400-bad-request-error-from-oauth20tokensrf-during-authorization-code-grant?forum=messengerconnect), that the request is GET not POST.
so, I created a GET request in ruby as follow:

```
access_code =params["code"]
uri = URI.parse("https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE  
http.read_timeout = 500
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new("https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf", 
                         initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})        
data = URI.encode_www_form({'client_id'=> 'my_client_id' , 
                         'redirect_uri' =>'my_redirect_url', 
                         'client_secret' =>'my_client_secret', 
                         'code'=>access_code, 'grant_type' =>'authorization_code'})
req.body = data
res = http.start { |http| http.request(req) }
```

When I run this I am getting the same HTTPBadRequest 400 error.

Note: I have checked the values of `CLIENT_ID,REDIRECT_URI,CLIENT_SECRET,AUTHORIZATION_CODE` it's all perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I regret seeing that forum to solve this problem and wasted my time.

actually POST request will do good in this situation as show in thier documentation.

This is how I got the response,

```
uri = URI.parse("https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new("https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf")
req.content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"       
data = URI.encode_www_form({'client_id'=> 'my_client_id' , 'redirect_uri' =>'my_redirect_ui', 'client_secret' =>'my_client_secret', 'code'=>access_code, 'grant_type' =>'authorization_code'})
req.body = data
response = http.request(req)
```